# Injecting parents into composite constructors with Unity C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to get IoC working with Unity in C# with the idea of a passing a wrapper/composite class into the children.

The top level class that composes multiple classes provides some common functionality that the composed classes require access to.

To illustrate:

```
// The top composite class
public class Context : IContext {
  public ISomething SomethingProcessor { get; }
  public IAnother AnotherProcessor { get; }

  public Context(ISomething something, IAnother another) {
    this.SomethingProcessor = something;
    this.AnotherProcessor = processor;
  }

  // A function that individual classes need access to, which itself calls one of the children.
  public string GetCommonData() {
    return this.AnotherProcessor.GetMyData();
  }
}

public class Something : ISomething {
  private _wrapper;
  public Something(IContext context) {
    this._wrapper = context;
  }

  // This class has no knowledge of IAnother, and requests data from the master/top class, which knows where to look for whatever.
  public void Do() {
    Console.WriteLine(_wrapper.GetCommonData());
  }
}

public class Another : IAnother {
  public string GetMyData() {
    return "Foo";
  }
}
```

If you didn't use IoC, it's easy, as the constructor for the Context class becomes:

```
public Context() {
  this.SomethingProcessor = new Processor(this);
  this.AnotherProcessor = new Another();
}
```

But when you're using IoC, the idea of "this" doesn't exist yet because it is yet to be constructed by the injector.  Instead what you have a is a circular dependency.

```
container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>();
container.RegisterType<IAnother, Another>();
container.RegisterType<IContext, Context>();

var cxt = container.Resolve<IContext>();  // StackOverflowException
```

The above example has been greatly simplified to illustrate the concept.  I'm struggling to find the "best practice" way of dealing with this kind of structure to enable IOC.

Comment: Well you have a circular dependency as you said. `You have a Context that needs ISomething that needs Context  that needs ISomething that needs Context  that needs ISomething that needs Context  that needs ISomething, etc....` You need to decide where to break the chain. It seems like you are mixing in too many concerns into one place. Maybe a factory pattern can help you construct your Context by using things available in the DI. You probably don't want your Context in the DI ... as this is what is going to happen. So your static factory class will construct the Context as you need it

Comment: @ppumkin, I often saw such "double binding" pattern (some kind of big controller class has dependencies, and those dependencies need to somehow "report" to the parent). But I agree with your comment above, it smells bad of concern mixing, and the use of a factory pattern looks promising. Could you make an answer out of that ?

Comment: related, from Software Engineering : [How to solve circular dependency?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306483/how-to-solve-circular-dependency)

Comment: Really the problem here is the dependency of a "thing" in two or more places... In my answer I try to elaborate on how to break this out. End of the day whatever solves your problem and makes it work is going to be OK...but thinking into the future you really want your code to be easy to understand.

Comment: I guess the context class is probably better known as an Orchestrator, for domain logic.  The reason for returning to the orchestrator for information is to try and keep separation of concerns.  Instead of having IAnother and ISomething do duplicate or similar work, they should refer to each other.

Comment: and did it work? :) Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the name of this pattern, or even if it is a bad or good practice, but you can solve your problem of "double-binding" by creating a method to bind the "IContext", instead of doing it in the constructor.

For instance,

1) `ISomething` has a `void BindContext(IContext context)` method

2) You implement it as such :

```
class Something : ISomething 
{
   IContext _wrapper;

   // ... nothing in constructor

   public void BindContext(IContext context)
   {
        _wrapper = context;
   }
}
```

3) Remove the `IContext` dependency injection in Something constructor.

And you call it from the context constructor :

```
public Context(ISomething something, IAnother another) {
    this.SomethingProcessor = something;
    this.SomethingProcessor.BindContext(this);

    // same for IAnother
}
```

And you do the same for `IAnother`. You could even extract some common interface "IBindContext" to make things a beat more "DRY" (Don't Repeat yourself) and make `IAnother` and `ISomething` inherit from it.

Not tested, and again : not sure it's the best way to do such dependency design. I'll be glad if there is another answer which gives a state-of-the-art insight about this.

Comment: I've selected this as the answer as I feel it achieves my objectives the cleanest.  It allows the orchestrating top class to continue to contain all logic for grouping and configuring the composite classes, whilst still maintaining IoC.

A similar approach of using a Property instead of a Method could be used which is pretty much straight "Bastard Injection".

Answer (score 2):

Factory pattern is a way construct an object based on other dependencies or logical choices.

> Factory Method: "Define an interface for creating an object, but let
>   the classes which implement the interface decide which class to
>   instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to
>   subclasses" (c) GoF.
>
> Lots of construction.. hence the name Factory Pattern

A crude code sample that could be used with DI

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory {

  _anotherProcessor = anotherProcessor;

 public ContextFactory(IAnotherProcessor anotherProcessor) {
     //you can leverage DI here to get dependancies
 }

 public IContext Create(){
    Context factoryCreatedContext = new Context();

    factoryCreatedContext.SomethingProcessor = new SomethingProcessor(factoryCreatedContext )
    factoryCreatedContext.AnotherProcessor = _anotherProcessor;

    //You can even decide here to use other implementation based on some dependencies. Useful for things like feature flags.. etc.

    return context;
  }

}
```

You can get away with this, maybe? - but there is still the cyclic reference issue here and I would never commit this kind of code.

The problem here you need to concentrate on **Inversion Of Control** of that `GetCommonData`

Your `SomethingProcessor` should not rely on methods in another class. This is where In Inheritance could be used but Inheritance can become very complicated very quickly.

The best way forward is to **Identify the ONE thing** that is needed by both or many other places and break that out into a new Dependency. That is how you Invert Control.

**TIP:**

Don't overdo Interfaces- Use Interfaces where you think you will be working with Polymorphism, such as a collection of different objects that must promise you they have implemented a specific method/property. Otherwise you are over using Interfaces and increasing complexity. DI doesn't have to use Interfaces it can be a concrete implementation. Interfaces on Repositories are a good use since you can switch Databases out easily but Interfaces a factory like this is not really needed.

Comment: This solves the problem, but in order for this to work the top-level class needs to have a lot exposed and in the end you land up with two classes doing one piece of work (the encapsulating orchestrator, and the factory).  Whilst Factories are useful tools, this time I don't think it scratched the itch I was looking for.  Thank you for your thoughts and detailed answer.